# Ler método privado - Ruby

Tags: ruby

Olá, pessoal.

```
class Automovel

  def self.tipo_cambio
    puts "Manual"
  end

  def acelera
    verifica_combustivel()
    # Injetando combustível
    puts "Acelerando automóvel"
    freia()
  end

  private
    def verifica_combustivel
      puts "verificando combustível!!!"
    end
end

#-----------

class Carro < Automovel

  def freia
    puts "freiando"
    #acelera()
    verifica_combustivel()
  end
end
```

Ando estudando Ruby, e ao fazer esse código me deparei com uma dúvida.

Quando crio uma instância da classe Automovel no terminal (vulgo **carro = Carro.new**) ele lê normalmente o método **acelera** de Automovel dando o comando **carro.acelera** (retorna "injetando combustível" etc), mas ao chamar o método freia da classe Carro por carro.freia, ele retorna o método verifica_combustivel. Quero entender por que ele retorna normalmente se o método está privado e pode ser acessado somente pela classe Automovel?

Answer (score 0):

Os modificadores de acesso variam de linguagem para linguagem. No Ruby, métodos privados podem ser acessados por classes filhas.

Answer (score 0):

Renan, eu entendo que qualquer objeto do tipo automóvel tem acesso ao método privado que foi definido, já que Carro está herdando da class Automóvel.

Você pode entender melhor o conceito lendo aqui [na doc](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/private_method_defined%3F)

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue chamar um método privado dentro de uma subclasse porque você colocou ela dentro de um método publico.

A mesma lógica se aplica ao attr_accessor que nada mais é que um macro para dois métodos de escrita e leitura.